# Calculating win percentage for individual teams based on pandas df

Tags: pandas

Have a pandas df like shown below

```
HomeTeam    AwayTeam    Winner
Warriors    Cavaliers   1
Pistons     Rockets     0
Warriors    Rockets     1
Heat        Warriors    0
```

The winning team (home or away) is represented by the binary outcome in the Winner column. I want to calculate winning percentage overall for each team. How would I go about doing this?

Expected output would be something like

```
Team     Win%
Warriors 85%
Heat     22%
....
```

Comment: `0` means the winner is the "home" team?

Comment: also please add the expected output based on your input data for validation

Comment: Yes 0 means winner is home team.

Comment: Added expected output @anky_91.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `np.choose` to select the winner, and perform `.value_counts()` on both the winner and both teams, and thus calculate the ratio with:

```
np.choose(
    df['Winner'], [df['HomeTeam'], df['AwayTeam']]
).value_counts().div(
    df[['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam']].stack().value_counts()
).fillna(0)
```

Here we thus use `np.choose` to select the teams, and perform a value count, next we `.stack()` the `HomeTeam` and `AwayTeam` to obtain a series of values of the teams that played. We can then use `.values_counts()` to calculate how many times a team played. In case a team never appears at the winning side, that will result in a `NaN`. We can solve that by using `0` for these values.

With the given sample data, we obtain:

```
>>> np.choose(df['Winner'], [df['HomeTeam'], df['AwayTeam']]).value_counts().div(df[['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam']].stack().value_counts()).fillna(0)
Cavaliers    1.0
Heat         1.0
Pistons      1.0
Rockets      0.5
Warriors     0.0
dtype: float64
```

Here the `Cavaliers`, `Heat` and `Pistons` won all their matches, the `Rocket`s won half of their matches, and the `Warrior`s did not win any match.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for get winner team, counts values by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and divide by counts by all values of both columns with `ravel` and [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), for division is used [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html), then multiple by `100` and last convert `Series` to `DataFrame` by [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html) with [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
winners = pd.Series(np.where(df['Winner'], df['AwayTeam'], df['HomeTeam'])).value_counts()
all_teams = df[['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam']].stack().value_counts()

df1 = winners.div(all_teams, fill_value=0).mul(100).rename_axis('Team').reset_index(name='Win%')
print (df1)
       Team   Win%
0  Cavaliers  100.0
1       Heat  100.0
2    Pistons  100.0
3    Rockets   50.0
4   Warriors    0.0
```

**Details**:

```
print (winners)
Rockets      1
Heat         1
Cavaliers    1
Pistons      1
dtype: int64

print (all_teams)
Warriors     3
Rockets      2
Heat         1
Cavaliers    1
Pistons      1
dtype: int64
```